# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I create an app Ruby on rails, using postgis. After rake db:create, I run 
rake db:gis:setup. But it show:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not 
open extension control file 
"/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or 
directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis
```

I use postgres 9.5 or 10, it show same result.
How can I fix that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, install postgis on your system. 
Then In your postgres console run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
More details please check http://postgis.net/install/

Comment: It still: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: although when I check the version of postgres is 10.1

Comment: Have you created 'postgis.control' file successfully?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have not installed postgis yet :3. I was successful .Tks again :))

Comment: @midu My great honor!